# Is "form" an abbreviation, or has it ever been?

Tags: etymology

The word *form* as in "web form" or in my case "XML form" would be translated as *Formular* in German and *formulaire* in French. Which leads me to the question, though the entry of Wiktionary and Etymonline seems to point to the contrary, has it ever been an abbreviation of a longer word? And if it is the case, is this longer word still in use? If not, is there better alternative to this word in the following example?

> Please backup all the corresponding forms before applying the patch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Form is not an abbreviation. [According to etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=form), the meaning "a document with blanks to be filled in" is from 1855.

Note that the word [formulary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/formulary) is a false friend. It means "a book listing medicinal substances and formulas" or "a collection of prescribed forms (as oaths or prayers)". It is **not** the English word for Formular (German), formulaire (French), formulário (Portuguese) and formulario (Spanish). All these words are actually translated to English as "form".